# using thread callback to fire event through timer

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timer, delegates, callback

Ok I am using a vb.net dll class (not a form application).

In this class I am using a method that creates a timer and in the end will call a method that will throw an event.

`timerDriver = New System.Timers.Timer()`

`timerDriver.Interval = 500`

`timerDriver.Enabled = True`

`AddHandler timerDriver.Elapsed, AddressOf DriverLicenseInTray`

I'm gonna describe part of the process as if it were working

So the user presses a button on a .asp page that starts the scanner.  Once the scanner has been started, the timer process is constantly listening without locking out the page (basically this process does not effect anything the user is doing).  Now, the software is watching for a card to be inserted into this scanner.  As soon as this is true, it calls a method that processes the card.  After the card has been processed it calls `RaiseEvent ProcessCard` which throws the event to a .asp page that has an appropriate event handler.

The issue I'm having is `RaiseEvent`.  It is raising it on the wrong thread because of the timer.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've searched and I see that I will probably have to use a delegate BUT i don't have  Me.Invoke or anything.invoke.  and if i'm right, invoke is what fires the event on the main thread?  I've searched the msdn pages like crazy and their fixes are not fixing mine.

I know that the RaiseEvent to the .asp is working because if i throw that on the main method, before the timer, the .asp page catches it.

Comment: Not realizing that the browser is normally hundreds of miles away from the data center that runs the ASP server is a common mistake.  What machine is this scanner hooked up to?

Comment: The scanner is hooked up to the client machine.  The .asp page is on a server, but I am able to raise events to it if i'm not using the timer.  The timer is causing it to raise on another thread.  I think I'm basically needing a way to write a delegate threaded callback.  I have found examples online, but none of them work for me.

Comment: You do sound hundreds of miles away from solving this.  This requires something like a POST or Ajax to tell the server about it.  How you plan to have the browser interact with custom hardware is very unclear.

Comment: i have an object tag called objScan that holds the object on the page.  When my dll fires an event, as long as I put objScan_eventName on the asp, it catches it.  The communication between server and dll is working so I'm close.  All I have to do now, is from the dll (forget the .asp page even exists), I need the event from the timer, to be raised on the main thread.

A timer creates threads which is why when I fire an event, the .asp doesn't catch it because the event is being fired on another thread.    I need to fire it on the Main thread.  basically a thread Call Back method.